# Use both suspend-freeze and pm-suspend

Tags: 13.04, suspend, intel, ultrabook

I'm using Ubuntu Raring and mainline kernel 3.9.4

I like the fast resume times pm-suspend-freeze is capable of, however I still want to have the lower power consuming suspend available. From what I've read it's only possible to use one or the other:
http://kernelnewbies.org/LinuxChanges#head-82ff281c802c350623a8b7dec846e8754a87ef40

Ideally, I'd be able to close my laptop and ps-suspend-freeze would be executed. However if I went in the power menu and chose suspend in the top right of Unity the traditional pm-suspend (to memory) command would be executed.

This would give me the ability to hop in and out of suspend-freeze and quickly use the laptop, close the lid and save power by idling. And if I plan to not use it for a few hours, suspend to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power savings in the freeze state are almost nothing, so if you have a working suspend to ram, you should stick with that.  It normally only takes around 3-4 seconds so should be plenty snappy.  Most of that time is usually dominated by waiting for the hard disk to spin up, so if you really want fast suspend/resume, you can disable that with:

```
sudo -s
cd /sys/block/sda/device/scsi_disk/*
echo 0 > manage_start_stop
```

This will leave the disk off when you resume until you actually try to access it, giving more power savings and faster resume.